# Looping over a list of strings in excel VBA

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I am trying to write a macro that when run in an excel sheet will select a specific column and there will replace all instances of a list of strings with a list of other specific strings. For example, any instance of "string a1" will be replaced with "string a2",  any "string b1" to "string b2", etc'.

So after selecting the column I need to run

```
Selection.Replace What:="string a1", Replacement:="string a2", LookAt:=xlWhole    
Selection.Replace What:="string b1", Replacement:="string b2", LookAt:=xlWhole
etc'
```

Now I would like to create a loop to run through the two lists, but I can't figure out what kind of loop can be used for this.
I would appreciate suggestions about how to do this from a list in a (hidden) sheet, or from a list defined in the VBA module.
Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you need to replace all instances of string a in a larger data-set with string b? Or do you have two columns and need to replace all of the entries in the second with the first? Could you provide a clearer example of your data, and maybe some things that you've already tried?

Comment: @F. Stephen Q I will add and edit with some more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the fastest way how to interact with a large number of cells is by saving them in the memory.

I personally would store all the strings in a list of strings `Dim sArray() as String`, where afterwards I would simply loop from the first element to the very last like following:

```
Dim iCounter as Long

For iCounter = lbound(sArray) to UBound(sArray)-1 (based on the update below)
   sArray(iCounter) = '...string manipulation logic here'
Next iCounter
```

**EDIT**

I don't quite know how exactly you would like to populate this array, but let's say that your values are in a cells of A1 to the very last cell of column A, then you can do the following

```
'initialize initial array
ReDim sArray(0 to 0)

'now loop through the cells
For iCounter = 1 to Range("A999999").End(XlUp).Row 
    If Range("A" & iCounter).value <> vbnullstring then
        'we don't want to store empty strings, right?
        sArray(UBound(sArray)) = Range("A" & iCounter).Value
        ReDim Preserve sArray(0 to UBound(sArray)+1)
    End If       
Next iCounter
```

Comment: could you please add an example of the code that populates the `sArray` list?

Answer (score 1):

After putting the pairs into a hidden worksheet, loop through them like this:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = [HiddenSheet!A1]
Do Until IsEmpty(r.Value)
    [MainSheet!A:A].Replace r.Value, r.Offset(0, 1).Value, xlWhole
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```